# Customize Devise Gem by override Controller actions and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my project, the `sign_up`, `sign_in` form will display in homepage instead in `users/sign_up` and `users/sign_in` as devise does. And when user didn't enter the info correctly in email & password field, instead going back to `users/sign_up`, we only show the homepage again.

I try to find how to customize the path and showing the view but I cannot.
So I customize it myself by override the `` `registrations_controller `` and the `sign_up` form. Here is my customize codes:

**RegistrationsController**: just change the `responds_with` to `` `redirect_to ``

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      redirect_to root_path, error: "Please check again"
    end
  end
end
```

In **routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

In ***sign_up_form*** (devise/registrations/new.html.haml):
Only change the `form_for resource, as: resource_name...` to `User.new` and `:user`

```
%h3 Sign up
= form_for User.new, :as => :user, :url => registration_path(:user) do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control'
  .form-group
    = f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password', class: 'form-control'
  .privacy
    By clicking Join Now, you argeed User Argeement InterestWeShare 's Privacy Policy and Cookie Policy.
  = f.submit "Join me in!", class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

I think my code isn't good, because I just change a little bit in controller, but I must rewrite the action by my self (although just copy code - not good for the best practise). and in the views, I don't know how we can customize the resource  and resource_name in a nicer way. Please help.

Comment: This might help you out: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

Comment: well, what is the problem ? Is there any error you particularly seeing. Is there anything you didn't understand. long ago i have hacked devise gem https://github.com/passion8/knockout-rails-devise-example , may be that will help you. Or ask specific thing.

Comment: Because I hacked devise gem too much, I think the gem is lack of flexibility and may be it isn't a good way.